# ASP.NET Core GZIP Encoding middleware works only if added twice

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, http, asp.net-core, gzip

I am trying to add GZIP Encoding to my responses from a web application (.NET Core 2.1)

I am following this [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/response-compression?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x)

According to it I have added the following lines in my Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<GzipCompressionProviderOptions>(options => options.Level = CompressionLevel.Fastest);
        services.AddResponseCompression(options =>
        {
            options.Providers.Add<GzipCompressionProvider>();
        });

        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

        // In production, the React files will be served from this directory
        services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
        {
            configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/build";
        });
    }

 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {

        app.UseResponseCompression();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseSpaStaticFiles();

        // Other middleware 
    }
```

I am doing this on a brand new WebApplication from the default WebApplication template (using React) that comes with .NET Core 2.1.

When I try to query a controller action on my application however, no encoding is applied whatsoever.

Inspecting the request/response with chrome does I have the following headers: 
[image: NoGzip]

The request headers include the **Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br** header, so  I think the request is not the issue.

Now here is the weird part. As soon as I add the `app.UseResponseCompression();` line **twice** I suddenly start getting some compression.

Here is what the headers look like after duplicating the `app.UseResponseCompression();` twice:
[image]

As you can see, the gzip header is present two times. (The size of the response is also considerably smaller, so gzip compression appears to be working)

Can anyone explain whats going on and why this is happening. The main issue with having the project setup this way, is that later in my pipeline I fail to decompress the request and I imagine this is due to some of the magic that happens here.

[This](https://nofile.io/f/egUNQ9p1x0c/WebApplication10.zip) is a sample web application that reproduces the issue. 
(Run The app, open localhost:5015 and navigate to Fetch Data. - observe what happens in the browser web console)

Comment: Works on my machine. Which runtime version do you use exactly?

Comment: "2.1.300". Taken form dotnet --version

Comment: Btw, you say it works on your machine. Did you make sure to remove the second duplicated line `app.UseResponseCompression(); (Startup.cs, line 52)

Comment: Yes, it works with one `UseResponseCompression()`.

Comment: How are you verifying it ? (I do it by checking chrome/post man for headers and byte size of the response :) )

Answer (score 0):

Having two instances of

```
Content-Encoding: gzip
```

implies that it has been gzipped twice, so you'd need to ungzip twice to get the intended effect.

Comment: Yes, thats what I though, but I can't even read it once, since trying to read the GZIP stream returns "The archive entry was compressed using an unsupported compression method."